# How to reference html select tag right away

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have two html drop down lists. When user selects one item in the first drop down list (database: location table), the second drop down list (product table) should dynamically change based on the user's selection in the first drop down. 
Then the second drop down should only list those products where location attribute = the selection in the first drop down.
So far what I have:

```
<td><select name="fromLocation" onchange=adduser.php style="width:150px;">
<option value='0'>- Select an item - </option>
<?php
    require 'dbConnect.php';
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM location");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['location'] . "'>" . $row['location'] . "</option>";
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: You would need to use some js for that, please make an attempt and come back if you get stuck - as there is no js here, the question is too broad and therefore off topic for SO.  Please see what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Comment: [Here are some ideas to get you started](https://www.google.com/search?q=populate+one+dropdown+based+on+selection+in+another&rlz=1C1GCEU_enGB821GB821&oq=populating+one+dropdown+based+on+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.9471j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) or [if you want to do this server side instead of using js](https://www.google.com/search?q=populate+one+dropdown+based+on+selection+in+another+php)

Comment: `onchange=someJSFunction()` then `someJSFunction` should fetch data using ajax from `adduser.php`

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire ajax call for this operation.

Call ajax function on the on change event of first drop down and by ajax call take the relevant value from database for second drop down.

after that on success part of ajax call , fill that drop down with that ajax call response.